# ASP - Create URL from main homepage?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, redirect

Ok, I am in need of creating vanity urls like so:

```
http://mysite.com/Barbash
http://mysite.com/Chatman
http://mysite.com/Glaser
... and so forth
```

These are people's last names.

Is there a way to do this in ASP without having to create a folder and place a redirect index.html file inside each one.  Basically I have 13 names, and doing this would be too much repetition.

But I also need to grab the last name from here as well and send it within the redirect to the other url.  So the other url will look something like this:

```
http://mysite.com/someverylongpath/page.html?name=Barbash
http://mysite.com/someverylongpath/page.html?name=Chatman
http://mysite.com/someverylongpath/page.html?name=Glaser
```

I am running a very old version of ASP on the site and IIS:

```
Microsoft-IIS/6.0 
ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.3082
```

How would you suggest I do this in ASP?  Should I add in ASP code into the `default.aspx` page in the actual root of the site?  If so, what should I add in the default.aspx page in order to make this possible?

Do I have to edit the `web.config` file in the root?  If so, how should it be changed to only account for these url paths?

Comment: This is done through url rewriting. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx Also, don't call it ASP, it's Asp.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is URL rewriting.

The best would be to upgrade your ASP.NET version because it is out of the box, but I found a link to explain it for an earlier asp.net version:
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/a-complete-url-rewriting-solution-for-asp.net-2.0/

Comment: Using `urlMappings` takes me to the webpage, but it doesn't load up any CSS/JS files that are relative... and makes the page not display properly...  But thanks, this is great!  So, I just need to change all relative urls to absolute.